# Vector tiles + Geojson: Can you use geojson shapes as a mask for tiles?

Tags: vector, d3.js, mapbox

I want to achieve the following:

I have some polygons projected in D3:

[image: neighborhoods]

Each of these polygons represents a different neighborhood, with streets and buildings and topography, all of which could be nicely represented with a vector tile. I'd like that as a background for each polygon.

However, each projection is transformed and scaled to its own SVG -- they're not on a larger background.

The way I know to use vector tiles is [against a large rectangular background](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150):

[image: vector]

How could I only project the tile inside the area of the neighborhood polygon(which is defined by the appropriate lon/lat). The background outside of each polygon should be null.

Comment: You could extract the `d` attributes of the `path`s and use them as clip paths.